# SE vs iFixit etc

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, policy

Regarding this answer - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/176247/85275

Ought we to leave sites like iFixit to the task of full take-aparts & just provide links?

The alternative would be pretty much to copy it verbatim… including 'borrowing' their photographs.

Personally, I feel this is one time where link-only answers are the correct way to handle this type of question.

Answer (score 2):

I say we should add value and summarize the key points of any external resource. Unless that resource is licensed under a similar creative commons license as the one we use here: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/ then you'll want to attribute anything that's copied more or less verbatim properly.

Also, the subscriber content portion of the "legal" agreement has good guidelines on what and how you choose to submit as an answer.

> http://stackexchange.com/legal